# Map builder recreates map from scratch each time?

Tags: scala

I've been digging around in the Scala code.  It looks like `TreeMap` uses the following builder class.

```
class MapBuilder[A, B, Coll <: scala.collection.GenMap[A, B] with scala.collection.GenMapLike[A, B, Coll]](empty: Coll)
extends Builder[(A, B), Coll] {
  protected var elems: Coll = empty
  def +=(x: (A, B)): this.type = {
    elems = (elems + x).asInstanceOf[Coll]
      // the cast is necessary because right now we cannot enforce statically that
      // for every map of type Coll, `+` yields again a Coll. With better support
      // for hk-types we might be able to enforce this in the future, though.
    this
  }
  def clear() { elems = empty }
  def result: Coll = elems
}
```

I don't understand the cast, but that's besides the point.  It looks as though, for example, when two `TreeMap`s are `++`-ed together, a new `TreeMap` is instantiated and then all the key-value pairs from both `TreeMap`s are added.  Since `TreeMap`is immutable, why can't we start from one of the `TreeMap`s and just add the items from the other?  Is this just because `++`works on both immutable and mutable types, so we need to make a defensive copy, and some collections may have more efficient strategies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is our code:

```
val a = TreeMap(1->'a, 2->'b)
val b = TreeMap(3->'c, 4->'d)
val c = a ++ b
```

Then `++` is defined in `TreeMap` as:

```
override def ++[B1 >: B] (xs: GenTraversableOnce[(A, B1)]): TreeMap[A, B1] = 
  ((repr: TreeMap[A, B1]) /: xs.seq) (_ + _)
```

So we start with `a` and fold each element of `b` into it to get the final result.

In other words, it appears to be doing exactly what you expected.  Or did I miss something?

Comment: You are absolutely right--I don't know how I missed that.  And thinking more the builder is probably written that way so it can handle map, filter, etc.

Comment: Right--and for converting to a different collection.